# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page in Struts2 application

Tags: java, jsp, exception, struts2

I am learning Struts2 and facing the below problem while hosting my application.
The `index.jsp` page, having /struts-tags example `<s:form>, <s:url>` etc, is throwing exception when the application is hosted.

**Jars used in the project:**

```
common-lang3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar
xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar
```

**Exception stack-trace:**

```
    **HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 12**
    **type** Exception report
    **message** An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 12

    **description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    **exception**
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 12

    9: </head>
    10: 
    11: <body>
    12:    <s:form action="empinfo" method="post">
    13:       <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" size="20" />
    14:       <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" size="20" />
    15:       <s:submit name="submit" label="Submit" align="center" />


    Stacktrace:

 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)

    **root cause**
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:84)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)

    **root cause**
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
        org.apache.struts2.views.util.DefaultUrlHelper.buildUrl(DefaultUrlHelper.java:180)
        org.apache.struts2.views.util.DefaultUrlHelper.buildUrl(DefaultUrlHelper.java:75)
        org.apache.struts2.views.util.DefaultUrlHelper.buildUrl(DefaultUrlHelper.java:70)
        org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer.renderFormUrl(ServletUrlRenderer.java:200)
        org.apache.struts2.components.Form.populateComponentHtmlId(Form.java:231)
        org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:801)
        org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:55)
        org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:53)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:104)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:74)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
```

**`index.jsp` page:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Form</title>
</head>

<body>
   <s:form action="empinfo" method="post">
      <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" size="20" />
      <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" size="20" />
      <s:submit name="submit" label="Submit" align="center" />
   </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="empInfo" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.EmployeeAction" method="execute">
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>HelloWorldStruts2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <!--<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>-->
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please suggest how can I fix this issue.

Comment: you're missing some jar, show your POM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have incomplete library jars deployed in your project. Try to download required jars from maven repository or look up them in the struts distro `lib` folder.

```
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
```

is missing.

See [how to create a maven project](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html).

Comment: I have a view page that uses <s:property> tag and it works OK

Comment: Thank you. The issue is now fixed. I had to include two commons-lang jars - commons-lang-2.4.jar and commons-lang3-3.1.jar. As commons-lang3-3.1.jar alone was not letting the application deploy.