# My Struts2 application gets Error 404: Resource not available

Tags: java, struts2

I was just trying my first struts2 application. Followed the steps from a tutorial. The link

```
    http://localhost:8080/StrutsApp/
```

and the link

```
    http://localhost:8080/StrutsApp/getTutorial.action
```

both give the same 'resource not available' error. I have added the required images of the error, directory structure, struts.xml, web.xml and the tutorialaction class.  Also the added jars(latest release from apache) can be seen in the directory structure.
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

My IDE: **Eclipse Kepler**

Server: **Apache Tomcat 7.0**

[image: The error]

[image]

[image: struts.xml]

[image: web.xml]

[image: Tutorial action class]

Comment: Try removing the forward slash '/' in '/welcome.jsp' and '/error.jsp' in struts configuration file

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Tried that. Getting the same error. I also have a Sysout(Hello from execute) in my action class and my console shows nothing after the tomcat server starts. So the method is not invoked. The problem seems to be with the xml files or jars. Can't understand !

Comment: can you please remove the struts2 portion in the web.xml and simply try to get the index.jsp

Comment: It seems like the app isn't even deployed. Check your tomcat logs.

Comment: Please post the logs, that information is really needed to help!

Comment: When I remove the 'filter' tags in the web.xml, the welcome.jsp and index.jsp both work fine. When i put the filter tags back, the same resource not found error.

Comment: Problem solved.Thanks for your help. There are two commons-lang jars. commons-lang-2.4 and commons-lang3-3.1 ! commons-lang3-x.x.jar was missing. Had just one of it in the Web-inf/lib folder.

Comment: Please post your answer. May be helpfull for another struts user!

Comment: @herry When commons-lang3 jar is missing it should throw `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20545369/573032) question. OP didn't post a stacktrace. When the application *is not deployed or wrong url entered* 404 error code from the web container guaranteed.

Comment: @RomanC ok, I agree. OP get another error message in log. But what offer you? Is better not post answer?

Comment: @herry You can post an answer if you have a right one but, first read comments. It could help you to formulate your answer in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved.Thanks for your help. There are two commons-lang jars with almost similar names which come in the struts2 zip file as follows:

1. commons-lang-x.x.jar
2. commons-lang3-x.x.jar

where x.x is the version number. Notice the ***'3'*** after lang in the second jar which is not present in the first jar.
The second one commons-lang3-x.x.jar was missing in my application. Had just the first one in the Web-inf/lib folder.