# Struts 2, "Resourse not found" on tomcat 7, jdk 1.7

Tags: java, struts2

I am exporting my Struts 2 project with eclipse into webapps.

It's my first strtuts program, but I am getting "resource not found" error on tomcat, after url localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts/index.jsp

My configuration : JDK 1.7, Tomcat 7, Struts lib 2.3

My code is,

Action Class

```
package com.home.struts;

public class HelloWorldAction{
   private String name;

   public String execute() throws Exception {
      return "success";
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.jsp

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.home.struts.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWorldStruts</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

in struts.xml , u need to give mapping `index.jsp` page, as your url denotes localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts/index.jsp

Sample code below, you need to modify your struts.xml accordingly:

```
<action name="index">
    <result>/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks for update, but still same error. And though error, atlease it should display file lists, when entered localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts

Comment: Would you like to check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727181/my-struts2-application-gets-error-404-resource-not-available.